# How to delay onSensorChange in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, accelerometer, sensors

I am new to android development. I am creating a simple app which moves a bitmap whenever sensors are changed. I am using Sensor TYPE_ACCELEROMETER 
but the problem is that it is moving bitmap too fast and bitmap is shaking at one place even when there is a slight change in sensor. all i want is to delay the onSensorChange return values 
so kindly help me 
here is my code fo SensorManager

```
public Can(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "hi");
        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if (sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {
            Sensor s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
            sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        }
        ball = BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
        test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        ClockStart = (float) System.currentTimeMillis();
        ballwidth = ball.getWidth();
        ballheight = ball.getHeight();
    }
```

here what onSensorChange does

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(16);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sensorY = event.values[0];
        sensorX = event.values[1];
    }
```

any help would really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely not what you want to do.  In fact, it will cause major problems.  If you're drawing too frequently, what you want to do is skip some calls to onSensorChanged.  If you're reacting to too small a shake, what you want to do is only set the sensorY and sensorX if the change is greater than a certain amount.

By the way, accelerometers are noisy.  Even if put on a flat stable surface it will jump around a bit.  You need to expect that to happen.

Comment: so which Sensor type i should use

Comment: Oh, the accelerometer is the right sensor type.  Its just that you need to put more intelligence into it.  Its giving you the raw sensor values, you need to filter it for noise and decide on how frequently to update your views.

Comment: but how would i do it sorry i am new to all of this